# Group Database data encoded as JSON using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Is there anyway to format JSON encoded data that is fetched from
mysql Database , with an index ?

**Example** :

The current JSON i have in text :

```
[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Luarb1"},{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Luarb2"}]
```

How i want it to be formatted :

```
{"1":[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Luarb1"}], "2":[{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Luarb2"}]}
```

Comment: that's not a valid json

Comment: @Federkun hello , that json is echoed using : 
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
return  json_encode($row);

Comment: To be clear, the first one is valid, the second is not. What is happening in the 2nd - do you just want them numbered, or do you want the category_id to be prepended to each entry?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter sorry for the missing brackets, the thing is i want to group the categories by their parent id so i can easily echo them without using other lines of codes. I thought that there could be a way but i don't know for sure.

Comment: Show your PHP code as well. Instead of manipulating the json string, manipulate the data(to get the desired json string) while fetching from the database itself.

Comment: @LuarbBalla I still don't know what you mean by 'parent id'. Where is that number coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// init variables
$arr = '[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Luarb1"},{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Luarb2"}]';
$new = [];

// decode JSON array
$decoded = json_decode($arr);

// create the new array to be encoded
$i = 1;
foreach ($decoded as $cur) {
    $new[$i++] = [$cur];
}

// encode the new array
$encoded = json_encode($new);

// test if everything worked
var_dump($encoded);

// tests.php:15:string '{"1":[{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Luarb1"}],"2":[{"category_id":"2","category_name":"Luarb2"}]}' (length=103)
```

Here is how I solved your problem, I didn't succeed in starting the array key at 0 but you wanted to be at 1 I think).

If you want the index from the database entry, you may need to improve your SELECT SQL query and retrieve id, then parse it in JSON and so on...